# Django: update_or_create, filter with list of kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there any way of using list in kwargs filter of `update_or_create`?

Here are my models:

```
class Partner:
    ...

class MyClassB:
    partner = models.OnetoOneField(Partner, related_name='some_name')
    ....
```

I tried using for loop, and it works fine.

```
# partners = list of queryset objects.

for partner in partners:
    MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner=partner, defaults= 
    {'name': None})
```

This operation is being used very frequently and I was thinking of optimizing this update_or_create. is there any way I could update all partners in one go? Something like:

```
MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner__in=[partners], defaults={'name': None})
```

This code is part of an API that would be hit by a thousand partners every 5 seconds. And I want to avoid additional overhead of using for loop here. Is there any optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner__in=[i.pk for i in Partner.objects.all()], defaults={'name': None})
```

you can use this list comprehension in the same line. or create a list and pass to the quesyset

```
partners = []
partner = Partner.objects.all() // or some filter
for i in partner:
    partners.append(i.pk)

MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner__in=partners, defaults={'name': None})
```

Comment: Using `MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner__in=[i.pk for i in Partner.objects.all()], defaults={'name': None})`

OR

`MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner_id__in=[i.pk for i in Partner.objects.all()], defaults={'name': None})`

Returns Exception, Column partner_id cannot be null. 

Isn't update or create supposed to pick partner_id from kwargs field and other fields from defaults dict?
How can we iterate over partner_id here?

Comment: how can it automatically take it?? you need to pass that from the kwargs

Comment: I believe I'm sending partner_id in kwargs while doing this:

`MyClassB.objects.update_or_create(partner_id__in=[i.pk for i in Partner.objects.all()], defaults={'name': None})`

As per my understanding, update_or_create finds instance based on filter we give in kwargs (in this case, partner_id). If it doesn't find any existing instance, it created a new one using defaults dict AND the data provided in kwargs (in this case partner_id).

Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: yes that's correct, if it finds a partner_id it will update the name you pass as default else it will create a new row, but while creating the new row in that class the partner_id is blank as you havent passed a default during that time, thus you are getting the error for creating new row

Comment: While creating new row, if I have to provide partner_id in defaults, then I think I'm back to initial problem. How would I iterate over partner_id? The partner_id to search in kwargs in first, and if record not found, the same partner_id to be used in defaults.
Could you help me understand this with one liner code please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, update_or_create, as far as I know, is intended to be use with a single object, not many.

But, inside of it, it searches the DB if the entry exists, and if so, updates it, otherwise creates a new one.

Since two queries are performed by the create_or_update, you could do the following without much overhead:

1. Retrieve all the entries that already exist:

```
existing_db_partners = set(MyClassB.objects.filter(partner__in=partners).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

2. Now create two lists: one with the existing partners, one with the ones that don't:

```
to_update = [partner 
             for partner in partners 
             if partner.id in existing_db_partners]

to_create = [partner 
             for partner in partners 
             if partner.id not in existing_db_partners]
```

1. At this point, it's very easy. Update the to_update, create the to_create, using bulk_create and bulk_update

I can't think of anything faster

NB: this has not been tested.